# Lower semicontinuity of the number of attracting periodic points of a holomorphic family of rational maps?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, ds.dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics, semicontinuity

Recently I have been reading the book [Mathematical Tools for One-Dimensional Dynamics](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/mathematical-tools-for-onedimensional-dynamics/C580F324B902D818AFD2E78FAFF10265).

In the proof of the theorem 5.4.2, authors use the following fact that the number of attracting periodic points of a holomorphic family of rational maps is lower semicontinuous. However, there is no reference to that fact throughout the book elsewhere. Could it be possible to direct me to the proof of this fact.

I am new to the site and therefore would appreciate any comment you might have on improving the quality of my question (Also, I wasn't quite sure to ask the question here or on math.StackExchange).

Comment: You didn't give all the details of the statement, but I suspect this boils down to the fact that if a holomorphic $f$ has a zero $z_0$, then also $g=0$ somewhere near $z_0$ for $g$ locally uniformly close to $f$ (this follows from Rouche's theorem or some such tool). Then apply this to $f^n-z$.

Comment: More precisely, if you have a holomorphic map continuously depending on parameter, and for some value $s_0$ of this parameter you have an attracting fixed point $a(s_0)$, then for $s$ close to $s_0$ there will be a fixed point $a(s)$ which is also attracting. So a map near the original one has at least as many attracting points as the original map.

Comment: Dear @AlexandreEremenko. Thanks for your reply. I have another question. In the given proof, afterwards, they use an argument that the local maxima are dense in the parameter space. I thought about it but couldn't see the reason. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: It depends on the exact form of the family of dynamical systems. This fact is unproved for $f_c(z)=z^2+c$ for complex $c$ but proved for real $c$ (with a very complicated proof).